# PowerShell Count String in TxT

Tags: powershell

I have this script. Can I count $err1, $err2, ... ?

```
$TodaysDate = Get-Date -UFormat "%d.%m.%Y %R"

$logFolder = "C:\Users\bogda\OneDrive\Desktop\TestFolder"

    function Read-Date {
  param(
    [String] $prompt
  )
  $result = $null
  do {
    $s = Read-Host $prompt
    if ( $s ) {
      try {
        $result = Get-Date $s
        break
      }
      catch [Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException] {
        Write-Host "Date not valid"
      }
    }
    else {
      break
    }
  }
  while ( $true )
  $result
}

Write-Host "Astazi este data de $TodaysDate"

$startDate = Read-Date "Enter Start Date"
$endDate = Read-Date "Enter End Date"

$output = switch -Regex -File $tempfile {
    '(\S+)\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}).+(\d{2}:\d{2})$' {

        $date,$time = $matches[2..3]

        $compare = [datetime]::ParseExact($date,'dd.MM.yyyy',$null)

        if($compare -le $startDate -and $compare -ge $endDate){
            continue
        }

        $vendor = switch -Regex ($matches.1){
            'asus' {'ASUS'}
            'microsoft' {'Microsoft'}
            'etcetera' {'etcetera'}
            default {'Unknown'}
        }

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Vendor = $vendor
            Date   = $date
            Time   = $time
        }
    }
}

$output | Group-Object -Property Vendor | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    "***$($_.count) errors $($_.name)***"
    $_.group | Group-Object -Property Date | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object -Begin {"    Details:"} {
        "    $($_.count) errors in $($_.group.date|Select-Object -First 1) - $($_.group.time -join ', ')"
    }
    ""
}

Set-Content -Path C:\Users\bogda\OneDrive\Desktop\TestFolder\textfile.txt -Encoding UTF8 -Value ($output | Group-Object -Property Vendor | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    "***$($_.count) errors $($_.name)***"
    $_.group | Group-Object -Property Date | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object -Begin {"    Details:"} {
        "    $($_.count) errors in $($_.group.date|Select-Object -First 1) - $($_.group.time -join ', ')"
    }
    ""
})
```

Exacly for what I need this script is to read in log folder Error in all files between 2 dates. After script is finish create and open .txt (notepad) file and show how many $err1 is , how many $err2... and after that in txt show line by line errors.

It is possible?

Thank you! :)

Machine_Errors.txt - create by script after finish job

```
eg. 
***errors $err1***
     Details: 
     2 errors in 28.10.2021 - 00:31, 01:43, .. 
     log.txt :
        00000124124012410ANOO00124Asus:03:00:22 10/28/21 00:31:55aCher # Ville3050000912 A-00-B55-C-AA
        9912399123910212fkwk--=Asus:00:00:00 10/28/21 01:43:02ivwww # 1929991Vlaiio0100000 BN-05-Cj004-aAgnT

***0 errors $err2***
     0 errors in 28.10.2021
```

Another important thing is the logs is not really .**txt.** (for Asus Machine is **log.0** and for Microsoft Machine is **log.jrn**)

logs.txt (where script search) looks like this (it's very strange- log doesn't have a pattern and the 'Asus (Asus:03:00:22 - error) Err return in most of case it's same with 'time' - format)

```
10000129412412412419-=-aaSelf991FJjkiqA
00000124124012410ANOO00124Asus:03:00:22* 10/28/21 00:31:55aCher # Ville3050000912 A-00-B55-C-AA
12049189248188128949LIOIQW--------i8999 10/28.21 00:32:27 9kkasfkk-asimc/1i2kkksd
9912399123910212fkwk--=Asus:00:00:00* 10/28/21 01:43:02ivwww # 1929991Vlaiio0100000 BN-05-Cj004-aAgnT
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output is rather strange. First I recommend we create some objects to represent the lines. I added some more examples to the sample log file.

```
$tempfile = New-TemporaryFile

@'
9129318727412asakfwa---------a124314Asus129 27.09.2021 KUR a 11:02
8981284182841ouiruqw---------v9591929Microsoft912009 27.09.2021 IRA a 11:55
1281284182848oiqwasq---------o901239lMicrosoft91200 28.09.2021 OLI a 20:42
9129318727412asakfwa---------a124314Asus129 27.09.2021 KUR a 12:22
9129318727412asakfwa---------a124314Asus129 28.09.2021 KUR a 09:11
9129318727412asakfwa---------a124314Microsoft129 28.09.2021 KUR a 04:44
8981284182841ouiruqw---------v959192Microsoft9912009 27.09.2021 IRA a 16:55
1281284182848oiqwasq---------o901239lMicrosoft91200 28.09.2021 OLI a 17:42
'@ | Set-Content $tempfile -Encoding UTF8
```

Using your `Read-Date` function, I set the `$startDate` and `$endDate` appropriately. Then with a switch statement we read the file while also extracting 3 bits of information. In the end what is output is a PSCustomObject with 3 properties, Vendor, Date, Time where the date is within the provided dates.

```
$startDate = Read-Date "Enter Start Date"
$endDate = Read-Date "Enter End Date"

$output = switch -Regex -File $tempfile {
    '(\S+)\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}).+(\d{2}:\d{2})$' {

        $date,$time = $matches[2..3]

        $compare = [datetime]::ParseExact($date,'dd.MM.yyyy',$null)

        if($compare -le $startDate -and $compare -ge $endDate){
            continue
        }

        $vendor = switch -Regex ($matches.1){
            'asus' {'ASUS'}
            'microsoft' {'Microsoft'}
            'etcetera' {'etcetera'}
            default {'Unknown'}
        }

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Vendor = $vendor
            Date   = $date
            Time   = $time
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can take our nice objects and do some grouping to extract the desired information and output in the specified format.

```
$output | Group-Object -Property Vendor | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    "***$($_.count) errors $($_.name)***"
    $_.group | Group-Object -Property Date | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object -Begin {"    Details:"} {
        "    $($_.count) errors in $($_.group.date|Select-Object -First 1) - $($_.group.time -join ', ')"
    }
    ""
}
```

This is the output

```
***5 errors Microsoft***
    Details:
    3 errors in 28.09.2021 - 20:42, 04:44, 17:42
    2 errors in 27.09.2021 - 11:55, 16:55

***3 errors ASUS***
    Details:
    2 errors in 27.09.2021 - 11:02, 12:22
    1 errors in 28.09.2021 - 09:11
```

Now you can just use `Set-Content` to write to a text file.

Pipe to `Set-Content`

```
$output | Group-Object -Property Vendor | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    "***$($_.count) errors $($_.name)***"
    $_.group | Group-Object -Property Date | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object -Begin {"    Details:"} {
        "    $($_.count) errors in $($_.group.date|Select-Object -First 1) - $($_.group.time -join ', ')"
    }
    ""
} | Set-Content -Path \path\to\textfile.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

or inline with a subexpression

```
Set-Content -Path \path\to\textfile.txt -Encoding UTF8 -Value ($output | Group-Object -Property Vendor | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    "***$($_.count) errors $($_.name)***"
    $_.group | Group-Object -Property Date | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ForEach-Object -Begin {"    Details:"} {
        "    $($_.count) errors in $($_.group.date|Select-Object -First 1) - $($_.group.time -join ', ')"
    }
    ""
})
```

Comment: Something doesn't work very well , I modify 'log' for test and script show me same value , same errors :D and if i put start date eg. 28.09.2021 - end date 28.09.2021 script search in 29.09.2021. I don't exactly understand what is the " $tempfile = New-TemporaryFile " and "'@ | Set-Content $tempfile -Encoding UTF8" inside the log file. 

Thank you again for your time!

Comment: That was simply for me to have a log file to work with. You would use your actual log files, which I don't have.

Comment: Share some more sanitized log file. That way we can test more. Also, you are using your Read-Date function for setting your start/end dates??

Comment: Hello Doug, I really apreciate your help. Real logs looks like this (edit first post). But when I try to open with notepad logs is not truncated ok, when I open with WordPad or Notepad++ is truncated ok. I have 2 different logs for each machine for Asus is in one format log.0 and for the Microsoft is in log.jrn (both can open txt)

Comment: Yes , I use read-date ; I edit my first post with your code and my Read-Date.